# Highlight div with new data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I've been looking around the net for answers on how you could show new content under a different coloured div and then when the user has clicked on that div it changes to the original set one. So you can tell the difference of whether its been seen or unseen.

Is this done with jquery alone, or does a database and php come into play? I have done some research, and I haven't found anything. So come to ask the experts in hope it may help somebody else.

So as a thought

```
if(message_status=1){
show new data coloured div
}else if(message_status=2){
show normal coloured div
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, more details would be needed to understand fully answer your question, but your sudo code is basically there.

```
//get data
var getData = $.ajax("your/endpoint", {your: params});
var NEW_MSG_COLOR = "#CCCCCC";
var DEFAULT_MSG_COLOR = "#FFFFFF";

getData.then(function (res) {
    //lets assume that the result of getting the data 
    //is an array of message objects
    $.each(res, function (msgIdx, msg) {
        var $div = $("<div />").text(msg.text);
        $div.css("backgroundColor", msg.status === 1 ? NEW_MSG_COLOR : DEFAULT_MSG_COLOR);
        $div.click(function () {
            $div.css(backgroundColor: DEFAULT_MSG_COLOR);
        });

        //do something with $div here, stick it in the page, etc...
    });
});
```

That should get you most of the way there.  The `$.ajax` assumes that you'll be doing an ajax call to get data somehow, but that's up to you (database, flat files, whatever...)

Comment: Fantastic Greg. I understand it clearly. Thank you for your help.